# How to fix a maxQueueLength error in Tibco?

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works, tibco-topic, tibco-designer

I get this error in TIBCO Administrator Log:

> (BW-EXT-LOG-200000 njams: maxQueueLength(=20) is reached.)

My client returns:

> Connexion to  refused.

Everything returns to normal after restarting the instances, but it takes a few minutes and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your **maxMsgs** property of that queue is set to 20 ? You can check this by connecting with tibemsadmin and show/changing queue properties. For Example:

```
tcp://localhost:7222> show queue Q1
 Queue:                 Q1
 Type:                  static
 Properties:            *prefetch=5,maxMsgs=1000,*store=$sys.nonfailsafe
 JNDI Names:            <none>
 Bridges:               <none>
 Receivers:             0
 Pending Msgs:          0, (0 persistent)
 Delivered Msgs:        0
 Pending Msgs Size:     0.0 Kb, (0.0 Kb persistent)
```

You can change it like this:

```
  tcp://localhost:7222> setprop queue Q1 maxmsgs=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Fixed

A process remained active so it allocated a space in the memory that it would not release.
This process contained a requestor for which the timeOut is not configured. it waited endlessly a response from the process containing the receiver which did not respond due to  an access issue to an external database.

Best Regards.